# how can PutExtra EXTRA_EMAIL for Action_send?

Tags: android, share

I have code that filter specific apps for ACTION_SEND intent.
But I can not set for gmail and mail EXTRA_EMAIL.

I try for this:

```
 String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
                       if(packageName.contains("email"))
                       {
                        emailIntent.setPackage(packageName);
                       }
                       else if( packageName.contains("android.gm") || packageName.contains("mail"))
                       {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.setType("text/plain");
                            if(packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, resources.getString(R.string.share_email_subject));
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"boghche.app@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

The EXTRA_EMAIL extra requires an array of String.  Use the String Array constructor

```
Intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "boghche.app@gmail.com" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this way.

```
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
  shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "urSubject");
  shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ExtraText");

  PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
  List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
   for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) 
    {
      if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("gmail")) 
       {
         final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
         final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
        shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
         shareIntent.setComponent(name);
         v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
         break;
       }
   }
```

Comment: what is v that u use? @PG_Android

Answer (score 0):

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("*/*");
                    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                            "subject name");


                        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                Uri.fromFile(new File(file.toString())));


                    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                    final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                            intent, 0);
                    ResolveInfo best = null;
                    for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
                        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm")
                                || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase()
                                        .contains("gmail"))
                            best = info;
                    if (best != null)
                        intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName,
                                best.activityInfo.name);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: by this way can u set email to?